# How to fix Xbox One Freezone.Reboot reboot cycle?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one

For those who have fallen victim to the 'backwards compatibility hack' which allegedly enables the Xbox One to play Xbox 360 games, but in fact results in an 'end-less' boot cycle - is there a solution to breaking out of this cycle and restoring normal operation?

Comment: Last resort: send in for repairs and hope that Microsoft won't charge you for it. After all, you're entirely responsible for bricking your own console.

Comment: Maybe you can force a factory reset? I read somewhere that holding the xbox button for 10 seconds will force a reset. But since I don't own one I wouldn't know.

Comment: Everything I've read has said that this completely bricks the console. I'm not sure there's any way to fix it, short of sending it off for repair.

Comment: Perhaps providing more details of the steps you took to reach your current situation would be benefitial.

Comment: The **dangerous** steps can be found here: http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2013/12/9/1386582636481/89b88547-87e4-4f54-b1df-4a13e95e5190-325x420.png

Comment: Those are the ones I was just looking at. Sounds like fun! This makes me want to buy an XBO more than any of the new games: to "brick" it.

Comment: How long do you get before it restarts again? Is it immediate or do you have time to press buttons?

Comment: After some digging, it looks like this is going to take a fix from M$. All that needs to be done is a factory reset to free up the machine. Yet at this point only M$ likely has the tools to do so without UI.

Comment: There is a possibility that the Offline System Update Diagnostic Tool might work.  I don't have an Xbox One to test this out though. http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/offline-system-update-diagnostic-tool

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have announced that people who have put their Xbox One into this state can revert it by restoring the console back to factory settings by selecting "Restore Factory Default" under the System menu in Settings.

Microsoft has suggested that if you are experiencing this issue and require further assistance that you should [contact their support centre, Xbox Support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/).

Comment: Hard to select a system menu item if your console is bricked.  I think contacting Microsoft Support is the best option in a case like this.

Answer (score 1):

After holding power button for 10 seconds unplug the power for 30 sec. After plugging it back in, hold the controller sync and eject buttons at the same time while powering Xbox One on. Keep holding those buttons until you hear a second power on noise. A troubleshooting screen should pop up giving you the option to factory reset or update offline. My Xbox One was bricked also and would freeze up whenever I touched any button on controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Microsoft's offline system update diagnostic tool using a USB stick. Head to the link below and scroll down to find the offline updates. You'll see file download links for **OSUDT1**, **OSUDT2** and **Restore Factory Defaults**. You need to download the **Restore Factory Defaults** file and follow the instructions on the page for preparing a USB flash drive, copying this update to it and how to use it to boot your Xbox One into manual update mode.

https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/system/offline-system-update-diagnostic-tool

Answer (score -1):

If anyone get in the scam of "freezboot" restart your xbox one go in setting in system and replace "freezboot" by "RETAIL" and it will return to normal.